# Small water leak where PVC meets copper

Tags: water-heater, pvc

I have a small leak at where the pvc joins the cold water copper flex pipe of the water heater.  How can I fix this?

Comment: Please add a picture of the place where the PVC joins the copper flex tube.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is a threaded connection, I swear by  [pipe joint sealing compound](https://www.acehardware.com/departments/plumbing/solvents-and-cements/plumbers-putty-and-sealers/4396321?store=15404&gclid=CjwKCAjwyY6pBhA9EiwAMzmfwWp4NaiDDL7dX2JgKqEbcP7EAWY9z1_km_VVDloc7MD5Xqo6o2NVVRoCT-0QAvD_BwE&gclsrc=aw.ds).

Of course you will need to turn the water off and open the connection to apply the compound to the threads.